# jquery $.each array index -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can a $.each object index - 1 ?

Because `obj[i - 1].day` doesn't work

```js
var checkin_status = [{
    "startdate": "2015-01-08",
    "totaldays": "4",
    "roadmap": [{
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 100,
        "day": 1
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 500,
        "day": 3
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1000,
        "day": 10
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1200,
        "day": 20
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 2200,
        "day": 30
    }]           
 }];
    
var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
    
$.each(checkin_info, function (i, obj) {
    var sum_day = obj[i - 1].day + obj.day;
    var middle_day = sum_day / 2;
    console.log(middle_day);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. the `sum_day` output should be `[4,13,30,50]`
2. divide into 2 , new output should be `[2,6.5,15,50]` this is all middle day between `[1,3,10,20,30]`

Comment: It will throw an error on your first item ("day":1) as it tries to access an element that doesn't exist (there is no item before your first item)

Comment: Surely `obj[i - 1].day` needs to be `checkin_info[i - 1].day` and you'll need to skip the first item for it to work.

Comment: @Jamiec use `checkin_info[i - 1].day` wil get `Cannot read property 'day' of undefined`

Comment: Why are you trying to use `i` as an index to `obj`? The `obj` argument will have the same value as `checkin_info[i]`.

Comment: but `obj` is the current element you're iterating over (as in the current object from `roadmap`) - that cant be an array. as @nnnnnn just said too!

Comment: @Jamiec how can i not to be skip the first item ?

Comment: You have to skip the first item, because you are trying to use *current item* and *previous item*. If you don't skip the first one what would the first iteration of the loop actually do?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need an `each` here at all, you're mapping one array to another, ive split this into two operations below to demonstrate but it does not need to be. It can all be done in one `map`:

```js
var checkin_status = [{
    "startdate": "2015-01-08",
    "totaldays": "4",
    "roadmap": [{
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 100,
        "day": 1
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 500,
        "day": 3
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1000,
        "day": 10
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1200,
        "day": 20
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 2200,
        "day": 30
    }]           
 }];

var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
var result1 = checkin_info.slice(1,checkin_info.length).map(function(e,i){
    return checkin_info[i].day + e.day;
});
console.log(result1); // logs [4,13,30,50]

var result2 = result1.map(function(e){
    return e/2;  
});
console.log(result2); // logs [2,6.5,15,50]
```

this can of course all be shortened to

```
var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
var result = checkin_info.slice(1,checkin_info.length).map(function(e,i){
    return (checkin_info[i].day + e.day)/2;
});
```

---

If you really *must* have an `$.each` you can use some of the same principles - slice off the first element:

```
$.each(checkin_info.slice(1,checkin_info.length), function (i, obj) {
    var sum_day = checkin_info[i].day + obj.day;
    var middle_day = sum_day / 2;
    console.log(middle_day);
});
```

Comment: Hey, this is way neater.

Comment: I have to use `result2` in `$.each`

Comment: @ImHappy - why? Do you bang in a nail with a slipper? Right tool for the right job (Or, is this homework?)

Comment: this is not a homework , I use `$.each` to display all my object into the view. I need `result2` for condition , if `totaldays` is equal to `result2` , some of the `html` will display

Comment: @ImHappy so what do you need the sum of all the numbers in `result2`? If not why cant you just iterate over the resultant array. This answer does exactly what you asked for in your 2 bullet points in the question - but just in a much neater way than you're trying to do it!

Comment: middle day not [2,6.5,15,25]

Comment: Now youve lost me - Thats exactly the [result I get](http://jsfiddle.net/hugzdv34/)

Answer (score 0):

Special case the first entry, like this :

```
var checkin_status = [{
    "startdate": "2015-01-08",
    "totaldays": "4",
    "roadmap": [{
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 100,
        "day": 1
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 500,
        "day": 3
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1000,
        "day": 10
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 1200,
        "day": 20
    }, {
        "gifttype": "stars",
        "quantity": 2200,
        "day": 30
    }]           
 }];

var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap;

    $.each(checkin_info, function (i, obj) 
    {

        var sum_day = 0;
        if(i==0) 
        {
                  //this is the first entry, so we can't look back to the previous day.   
                  sum_day = obj.day; 
        }
        else
        {
                   //you were calling obj[i-1] here, which wasn't going to work.
                   //i presume you wanted the previous day here.
                   sum_day = checkin_info[i - 1].day + obj.day;
        }


        var middle_day = sum_day / 2;
        console.log(middle_day);
    });
```

Comment: any other way do in `$.each` ?

Comment: just noticed that and changed the answer.

Comment: $.each behaves different from normal loops. if you return a true, it will stop processing the current iteration and move on to the next.

Comment: if I change to checkin_info[i - 1].day first item will be skip. I dont want the first item to be skip . help

Comment: @ImHappy fixed it. good eye.
Also, how can we calculate the middle of the day if we don't skip the first item? that leaves no reference to the day before, so we can't make your calculation if we don't skip the first one.

Comment: if skip the first item whole thing is not correct = =

Comment: hang on, i think i get it.

Comment: You still get a different output from this, since you're now also handling the first one. (like you asked)

Answer (score 0):

$.each is not good for performance as every interation would call function. It is better to use the for loop in vanilla js.

```
var checkin_status = [
{"startdate":"2015-01-08",
"totaldays":"4",
"roadmap":[
            {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":100,"day":1},
            {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":500,"day":3},
            {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1000,"day":10},
            {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1200,"day":20},
            {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":2200,"day":30},
          ]

}];

    var checkin_info = checkin_status[0].roadmap,
        len = checkin_info.length,
        i,
        sum_day = [],
        middle_day = [],
        sum = 0;

    for(i=0; i< (len -1); i++) {
        sum = checkin_info[i].day + checkin_info[i + 1].day;
        sum_day.push(sum);
        middle_day.push(sum/2);
    }
    console.log(sum_day)
    console.log(middle_day)
```

Comment: well, it works. but the reasoning behind it is a little inane.

Comment: Look, we get that it's a little bit slower to use jquery's each. it's just so little overhead that you barely notice it on a data set like this.